# Flutter: How to use filterOption in photo_manager package

Tags: flutter, dart

I am puzzled on how to use filterOption for **durationConstraint** and **sizeConstraint** in ***photo_manager*** dart package. Can someone enlighten me on how to use it? Hint says I must use FilterOptionGroup()

```
List<AssetPathEntity> albums = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(
        onlyAll: true,
        type: RequestType.video,
        filterOption: FilterOptionGroup(),
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a `SizeConstraint`, define a `FilterOption` with that constraint and use it to set an option of the `FilterOptionGroup`:

```
SizeConstraint szc = SizeConstraint(
  minWidth: 0,
  maxWidth: 100,
  minHeight: 0,
  maxHeight: 100,
  ignoreSize: false,
);

final option = FilterOption(
  sizeConstraint: szc,
);

FilterOptionGroup filter = new FilterOptionGroup();
filter.setOption( AssetType.image , option );
```

Identically, you could set the `DurationConstraint` and set the respective option.

Comment: it is old question . but please if you still alive can you tell me how to flitter format of images , in your answer there seem no format options  ?