# How to filter only mp4 , png , jpg imagse/videos in photo_manager plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, photo-management

I am using  `photo_manager` plugin, but I am stuck on how to filter only the following files

images png , jpg

videos mp4

they don't mention on their docs of how to implement it

I have the following code but I can't find the method for my need

```
List<AssetPathEntity> albums = await 

PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(onlyAll: true,filterOption: FilterOptionGroup(???? );    

List<AssetEntity> photos = await albums[0].getAssetListPaged(  page: 0, size: 50, );
```

does it possible ?

Comment: are you looking for this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/66342969/17180860 ,

Comment: NO ....  at all , since i need filter the format of files